# Ansible script - error with pexpect module

Tags: ansible

I am writing ansible script to install universal forwarder but stuck using pexpect module.

Error I am getting:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pexpect'
fatal: [Server-a]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (pexpect) on **** Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}
```

I tried many workarounds like passing python interpreter in the command line while running ansible script.

Tried with both python versions 2.7 and 3.

I also see that pexpect is installed: pexpect-2.3-py2.7.egg-info

Answer (score 1):

Since the `pexpect` Python module is needed [on the nodes in a version greater or equal to ***3.3***](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html#requirements) and that there is a [`pip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) module to install python dependancies, what you could do is to write the `pip` task needed to upgrade your nodes dependancies to the right version on `pexpect`.

Something like:

```yaml
- pip:
    name: pexpect>=3.3

- name: This is just an expect demo
  expect:
    command: read -p 'What is the answer to life, the universe and everything?'
    responses:
      (?i)answer: 42
```

Those two would then yield:

```
TASK [pip] *******************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [This is just an expect demo] *******************************************
changed: [localhost]
```